# ERROR: permission denied for relation svv_redshift_databases

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to use the Redshift **Query Editor V2** connecting with Database username and password, in order to query my Redshift Cluster from AWS Console.

When from the left panel I try to expand the DB to explore relative schemas and tables I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: permission denied for relation svv_redshift_databases
```

This blocks me from explore tables within the Redshift cluster, any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Granting access to svv_redshift_databases allows to expand DBs within the Redshift Cluster but then you get blocked when expanding schemas with error message `ERROR: permission denied for relation svv_all_tables`. So if it's also required to expand schemas and tables is necessary to grant permission to svv_all_schemas and svv_all_tables as well in this way:

```
grant select on svv_redshift_databases to myuser;
grant select on svv_all_schemas to myuser;
grant select on svv_all_tables to myuser;
```

It has also been attached the AWS Managed Policy [AmazonRedshiftQueryEditorV2FullAccess](https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/policies/arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonRedshiftQueryEditorV2FullAccess).

After the above it was possible to explore schemas and tables from the Query Editor V2